# Forcing all laptop traffic to hop through a UK based desktop, before being VPNed to company network

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy

I have a laptop, which I travel with all around Europe.

I have a desktop at home, I use as a server and I have ssh access to it from my laptop. Let's assume I have a static IP etc, so no worries about DNS.

I have a work network at my office and I have to VPN into it to access whatever I need. While VPNed into I use a remote desktop app (Remmina), a linux terminal for ssh, and a web-browser to access intranet etc.

What I want to do, is run apps like Remmina and Chrome on my laptop, and route ALL traffic through my desktop at home, so that everything looks like it's coming from the home desktop, and my laptop IP address is not listed anywhere, just my home desktop.

I originally thought of using a VPN from my laptop to my home desktop, but presumably this only supports ports 80 and 443, I want every port's traffic bounced through my home desktop, just incase something changes. Also I don't know how my home desktop working as both a VPN server (from laptop to it) and a VPN client (from it to work) would work with each other.

Another solution I thought of is that I use the chrome and remmina installed on my home desktop, but run them through an ssh -X session between my laptop and home desktop, however while I think this would work, everytime I have tried to do this before, it has been painfully slow.

Finally, I believe I could set up a proxy, such that I forward traffic on specific ports though my home desktop, however Remmina does not support proxy configuration. And I don't like the idea of being dependent on a piece of software to execute this correctly.

So I want to ask, what would be the proper solution to this?

Thanks

Joey

Comment: It sounds like want to cheat your employer, those types of question are off-topic here.

Comment: Or, just access the desktop remotely though Remote Desktop and work on it like you're sitting in front of it. Why make things so complicated?